# Scraping multiple web pages has the same results as the first page using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My question is about that I tried to get the product names from CME group website. However, why the code be wouldn't be able to access the next page although I changed the URLs in the loop? Any ideas and opinions on this? Thanks in advance.

```
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(1,6):
 url='http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#pageNumber='+str(i)+'&sortAsc=false'

 CMEacess=Request(url,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
 print(url)
 print('page: '+str(i))

 CMEpage=urlopen(CMEacess).read()
 CMEsoup=BeautifulSoup(CMEpage,'html.parser')

 namelist=CMEsoup.findAll('th',attrs={'class','cmeTableLeft'})

  for name in namelist:
    print(name.get_text())

  print('\n')
```

Comment: In `url` replace `#` with `?`

Comment: That worked! Could you elaborate more?

Comment: The `?` signifies that what follows is a query string, so the arguments `pageNumber` and `sortAsc` get processed by the server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the requests library rather than urllib. I just accessed page 5 successfully using code similar to yours with this difference.

Note that the literal 'D3' appears on page five but not on page one.

```
>>> import requests
>>> i = 5
>>> url='http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#pageNumber='+str(i)+'&sortAsc=false'
>>> page = requests.get(url).content
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> soup.find_all(string='D3')
['D3', 'D3']
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But why using a string D3 has something to do with the product name? and I change my code to your format. But it still ended up giving me the same results after I change the number. But somehow @t.m.adam worked.

Comment: In my experience the requests library is usually a better bet than the urllib library. That was my starting position. This was a test of whether I could use the *form* of url that you had to get page 5 with requests. I simply chose the present of 'D3' as a marker in the page. Do you mean to say that with the code in my answer you still weren't able to get other parts of page 5?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. No, I still couldn't loop through the next pages via your format. But it did go through by changing # into ?.