# Web scraping: loop through different pages returns always content from first page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some data from the table at 'https://etfdb.com/screener/'. I am able to get the content for the first page but when I change the url to 'https://etfdb.com/screener/#page=X' where X = 1 to 90 I still get the same output of the first page

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
parsed = []
for page in range(1,90):
    url = 'https://etfdb.com/screener/#page='+str(page)
    resp = requests.get(url,headers={
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'
            })
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')

    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table table-bordered table-hover table-striped mm-mobile-table'})
    i = 0
    while i<len(table.find_all('td')):
    try:
        ticker = table.find_all('td')[i].text
        name = table.find_all('td')[i+1].text
        asset_class = table.find_all('td')[i+7].text
        parsed.append([ticker, name ,asset_class])
    except:
        pass
    i = i+8
```

even if I manually set the page number I still get the results of the first page
I have tried to change the "#page" to "?page" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664438/scraping-multiple-web-pages-has-the-same-results-as-the-first-page-using-python) but to no avail

Comment: the table is generated dynamically. So you need to let it render first. one option is to use Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using Selenium. Basically It gets the first page, then clicks on "Next". And it will continue until there is no more pages to go to.

The problem I was having was it was going too fast, so at some point it wasn't finding "Next" and crashing. I put a 1 second time delay (but there are better ways to do that, like implicit waits...I'm still learning how to use it correctly.)

But this will get you going.

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
parsed = []
url = 'https://etfdb.com/screener/'
driver.get(url)


while driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mobile_table_pills"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[8]/a'):
    try:
        resp = driver.page_source
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp, 'lxml')

        table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table table-bordered table-hover table-striped mm-mobile-table'})
        i = 0
        while i<len(table.find_all('td')):
            try:
                ticker = table.find_all('td')[i].text
                name = table.find_all('td')[i+1].text
                asset_class = table.find_all('td')[i+2].text
                parsed.append([ticker, name ,asset_class])
            except:
                pass
            i = i+8
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mobile_table_pills"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[8]/a').click()
        print ('Aquired page: %s' %(driver.current_url.split('page=')[-1]))
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        break


df = pd.DataFrame(parsed, columns=['Ticker','Name','Asset Class'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
     Ticker      ...        Asset Class
0       SPY      ...             Equity
1       IVV      ...             Equity
2       VTI      ...             Equity
3       VOO      ...             Equity
4       VEA      ...             Equity
5       QQQ      ...             Equity
6       EFA      ...             Equity
7       VWO      ...             Equity
8      IEMG      ...             Equity
9       AGG      ...               Bond
10     IEFA      ...             Equity
11      IJH      ...             Equity
12      VTV      ...             Equity
13      IJR      ...             Equity
14      IWM      ...             Equity
15      IWF      ...             Equity
16      IWD      ...             Equity
17      BND      ...               Bond
18      VUG      ...             Equity
19      EEM      ...             Equity
20      GLD      ...          Commodity
21      VNQ      ...        Real Estate
22      VIG      ...             Equity
23      LQD      ...               Bond
24       VB      ...             Equity
25       VO      ...             Equity
26      XLF      ...             Equity
27     VCSH      ...               Bond
28     USMV      ...             Equity
29      VEU      ...             Equity
    ...      ...                ...
2219    BDD      ...          Commodity
2220   WDRW      ...             Equity
2221   LACK      ...             Equity
2222   HONR      ...             Equity
2223   PEXL      ...             Equity
2224  FOANC      ...             Equity
2225    DYY      ...          Commodity
2226   HAUD      ...             Equity
2227    SCC      ...             Equity
2228   PASS      ...             Equity
2229   CHEP      ...       Alternatives
2230   EKAR      ...             Equity
2231    LTL      ...             Equity
2232    INR      ...           Currency
2233   BUYN      ...             Equity
2234  PETZC      ...             Equity
2235    SBM      ...             Equity
2236   RPUT      ...       Alternatives
2237    SZO      ...          Commodity
2238    EEH      ...             Equity
2239   HEWW      ...             Equity
2240    FUE      ...          Commodity
2241    AGF      ...          Commodity
2242  GRBIC      ...             Equity
2243    VSL      ...             Equity
2244   DLBL      ...               Bond
2245    BOS      ...          Commodity
2246     LD      ...          Commodity
2247    BOM      ...          Commodity
2248    DDP      ...          Commodity

[2249 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The pagination actions of the site are dynamic, thus, you need to use `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
def get_content(_d):
  _headers = [re.sub('\n', '', i.text) for i in _d.find('table').find('tr').find_all('th')]
  _, *data = list(filter(None, [[re.sub('\n', '', i.text) for i in b.find_all('td')] for b in _d.find_all('tr')]))
  return [dict(zip(_headers, i)) for i in data]

d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://etfdb.com/screener/')
all_data = [get_content(soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser'))]
_next = [i for i in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') if re.findall('^next', i.text, re.I)]
while _next:
  _next[0].send_keys('\n')
  all_data.append(get_content(soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')))
  _next = [i for i in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') if re.findall('^next', i.text, re.I)]
```

Sample output (first page only, due to SO's answer character limit):

```
[{'Symbol': 'IVV', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Core S&P 500 ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$159,613.22', 'YTD': '11.41%', 'Avg. Volume': '6,062,749', 'Previous Closing Price': '$280.32', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VTI', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard Total Stock Market ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$107,909.21', 'YTD': '12.40%', 'Avg. Volume': '4,901,940', 'Previous Closing Price': '$143.46', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VOO', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard S&P 500 ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$102,814.11', 'YTD': '11.43%', 'Avg. Volume': '4,474,837', 'Previous Closing Price': '$256.07', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VEA', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard FTSE Developed Markets ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$70,063.68', 'YTD': '9.97%', 'Avg. Volume': '22,225,420', 'Previous Closing Price': '$40.80', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'QQQ', 'ETF Name': 'Invesco QQQ', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$68,001.87', 'YTD': '12.27%', 'Avg. Volume': '48,660,348', 'Previous Closing Price': '$173.19', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'EFA', 'ETF Name': 'iShares MSCI EAFE ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$65,100.01', 'YTD': '9.34%', 'Avg. Volume': '39,227,020', 'Previous Closing Price': '$64.27', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VWO', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$62,464.73', 'YTD': '9.24%', 'Avg. Volume': '21,504,412', 'Previous Closing Price': '$41.62', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'IEMG', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Core MSCI Emerging Markets ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$58,650.02', 'YTD': '8.42%', 'Avg. Volume': '23,205,799', 'Previous Closing Price': '$51.12', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'AGG', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Core U.S. Aggregate Bond ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Bond', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$58,023.69', 'YTD': '0.79%', 'Avg. Volume': '6,496,300', 'Previous Closing Price': '$107.07', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'IEFA', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Core MSCI EAFE ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$57,206.30', 'YTD': '9.62%', 'Avg. Volume': '15,197,579', 'Previous Closing Price': '$60.29', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'IJH', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Core S&P Mid-Cap ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$48,274.19', 'YTD': '15.12%', 'Avg. Volume': '2,089,207', 'Previous Closing Price': '$191.16', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VTV', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard Value ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$46,173.50', 'YTD': '10.02%', 'Avg. Volume': '2,821,418', 'Previous Closing Price': '$107.76', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'IJR', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Core S&P Small-Cap ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$44,864.19', 'YTD': '15.44%', 'Avg. Volume': '5,460,632', 'Previous Closing Price': '$80.02', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'IWM', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Russell 2000 ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$43,733.85', 'YTD': '17.09%', 'Avg. Volume': '26,073,227', 'Previous Closing Price': '$156.78', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'IWF', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Russell 1000 Growth ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$42,024.32', 'YTD': '12.77%', 'Avg. Volume': '2,928,795', 'Previous Closing Price': '$147.63', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'IWD', 'ETF Name': 'iShares Russell 1000 Value ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$38,059.34', 'YTD': '11.08%', 'Avg. Volume': '4,668,100', 'Previous Closing Price': '$123.35', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'BND', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard Total Bond Market ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Bond', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$37,358.63', 'YTD': '1.02%', 'Avg. Volume': '2,981,882', 'Previous Closing Price': '$79.82', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VUG', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard Growth ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$36,989.43', 'YTD': '13.23%', 'Avg. Volume': '1,319,368', 'Previous Closing Price': '$152.10', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'EEM', 'ETF Name': 'iShares MSCI Emerging Markets ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$34,442.08', 'YTD': '8.65%', 'Avg. Volume': '89,719,367', 'Previous Closing Price': '$42.44', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'GLD', 'ETF Name': 'SPDR Gold Trust', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Commodity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$33,249.82', 'YTD': '2.26%', 'Avg. Volume': '8,782,053', 'Previous Closing Price': '$123.99', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VNQ', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard Real Estate Index Fund', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Real Estate', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$32,604.41', 'YTD': '12.63%', 'Avg. Volume': '8,538,158', 'Previous Closing Price': '$83.99', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VIG', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard Dividend Appreciation ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$32,584.13', 'YTD': '11.19%', 'Avg. Volume': '1,610,603', 'Previous Closing Price': '$108.91', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'LQD', 'ETF Name': 'iShares iBoxx $ Investment Grade Corporate Bond ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Bond', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$32,520.19', 'YTD': '3.16%', 'Avg. Volume': '9,748,131', 'Previous Closing Price': '$116.03', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'VB', 'ETF Name': 'Vanguard Small Cap ETF', 'Asset ClassNew': 'Equity', 'Total Assets ($MM)': '$24,678.09', 'YTD': '17.14%', 'Avg. Volume': '1,025,374', 'Previous Closing Price': '$154.61', 'Overall Rating': ''}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}, {'Symbol': 'Export to CSV with ETFdb.com Pro'}]
```

This solution utilizes a `while` loop to continuously click the "next" button to progress through the pages. Rather than relying on scraping the first five results, this can handle as many pages as the site provides.